# How to can extract data from a <script>window.Flourish

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, iframe, script-tag

I am trying to extract data from a website that uses Flourish. It uses JavaScript to load the data via Flourish link (`iframe`) I believe. The data is in a `script` tag.

Full Xpath" `/html/body/main/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/script`

and then iframe Full Xpath: `/html/body/script[4]`

The data is after

`"var _Flourish_data_column_names"` and `"_Flourish_data ="`

I have had success using selenium, but having issues using it on my main computer. I would like to be able to use BeatuifulSoup.

Answer (score 0):

what's the url?

Potential Solutions: (in javascript)

- Solution 1: find the start and end index (String.indexOf) and get substring between them (String.slice)
- Solution 2: use regular express (String.match)
- Solution 3: find the open and close character, such as {}/[]